# How would you solve this inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x + 3^x < 4$

The answer is obviously x < 1, but I'm not sure how to solve it algebraically.

Comment: One is not correct.

Comment: It may help to note that $x+3^x$ is strictly increasing with $x$.

Comment: You don't need algebra. Just explain why $x < 1$ is obvios to you. (See @EthanMacBrough 's comment.)

Comment: @JohnDouma, i meant $x<1$, fixed,

I understand that i could just use $x+3^x = 4$ to solve for x (say x = y), and then since it's strictly increasing, claim that x < y. But i can't even solve for $x+3^x = 4$.

It's 1 because I guessed and it worked, and then I graphed it. I was thinking there was some algebra with logarithms that could solve for x that I was missing.

Comment: @DavidDavidson inverting $x+3^x$ is non-trivial and requires product logarithms. I think for the problem you're supposed to just guess the answer.

Answer (score 1):

More interesting could be the problem of
$$x+3^x < k \qquad \forall k >0$$
So, consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=x+3^x - k$$ Its derivative is always positive and the zero is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$x_{sol}=k-\frac{W\left(3^k \log (3)\right)}{\log (3)}$$ So, because $f'(x)>0$ then 
$$x+3^x < k \implies x <x_{sol}$$